# How to get cypress to return children length of 0 when there isnt any children

Tags: testing, cypress

So I am writing a test that will add a card to a container(payment-card-container) and I want to confirm an element was added later by seeing if the children have increased by 1. But I am having issues when we try to count the children length when there isnt any. I am currently using the below:

```
cy.get('[data-test-id="payment-card-container"]')
    .children()
    .its('length')
    .then(length => {
        const childrenLength = length;
    })
```

But Cypress seems to get an error because it cant find the children (Error below).

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: ``, but never found it.
```

Is there a way this can work when there isnt any children and it returns the value of 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using a jQuery expression like

```js
Cypress.$('[data-test-id="payment-card-container"]').children().length
```

is you don't get the Cypress retry for async updates.

If adding a payment card calls an API, the above expression will **falsely report 0 children** instead of waiting for the DOM to update.

There's really no good way to handle the no-cards situation,

***Except***

- set up your test scenario such that there are no cards initially
- add a card
- confirm that there is now exactly one card

If you must test for zero children, a trailing `.should()` will remove the error message.

```js
cy.get('[data-test-id="payment-card-container"]')
  .children()
  .should('have.length', 0);   // no error when should expression passes

// Add card here

cy.get('[data-test-id="payment-card-container"]')
  .children()
  .should('have.length', 1);   // waits for async add-card operation
```

Tested with

```html
<body>

  <div data-test-id="payment-card-container"></div>

  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const div = document.querySelector('[data-test-id="payment-card-container"]');
      const p = document.createElement('p')
      div.appendChild(p)
    }, 2000)
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

One hacky way that I could think of is this. You can use the jQuery [length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) and [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) property to check the length:

```
cy.get('body').then(() = > {

    if (Cypress.$('[data-test-id="payment-card-container"]').children().length == 0) {
        //Do Something
    }
    else {
        //Do Something
    }
})
```

Comment: Good approach! Just a random thought - if you are using the JQ command, do you even need to get the body? I think it is needed only if we use the vanila JS approach `body.find()`

Comment: Yes, you don't need it. I wrote it to make sure that we have the body loaded and then the commands are run. Depends on how OP wants to use these in tests.

Comment: It's not really hacky, it accurately reports a ***static*** scenario, but falls down when the cards are added asynchronously. Really only useful when you know the children count is zero, but then you don't need to measure it.

Comment: Thanks this approach also does work for me.

Comment: @Alapan Das Does it ensure all sub elements are loaded? Because I had been searching for such thing for over a year with no success. Doesnt JQ function `document.ready()` work even better in that case?